# Javascript Cryptography - Convert a Character into another Character

Tags: javascript

I am trying to develop a browser-based text conversion tool in which I can write a normal english text message such as "Hello world" and convert each character into the character defined by my cipher - which in this case becomes "A#EC#C#Ab EdAbFbC#D".

There is a one-to-one mapping for each character. So far I have laid out the pre-computed cipher as

```
var map { 
  a : "A";
  b : "B";
  c : "C";
  d : "D";
  e : "E";
  f : "F";
  g : "G";
  h : "A#";
  i : "E#";
  j : "B#";
  k : "F#";
  l : "C#";
  m : "G#";
  ...
}
```

And so on.

The question is - How do I take the text input from an html text box (such as "Hello world") and convert the characters into the corresponding character from the map into another text box (giving "A#EC#C#Ab EdAbFbC#D")?

Comment: This isn't valid JavaScript. What's `;` doing there? What is `var map { ... }`?

Comment: You will also have trouble substituting it back. You should probably use a different map, where each character is substituted for **one** other character.

Comment: I think you would like to know this is a very insecure way of "protecting" things :) - If you wanna know why its insecure I suggest that you take the Cryptography course at Khan Academy, will take you less than an hour and its free

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple, really:

```
var result = myString.split('') // Split the string into an array
    .map(function(c){          // Replace the characters in the array
        return map[c];
    })
    .join('');              // Rebuild the string from the resulting array.
```

Your `map` object needs to be declared a little differently, though:

```
var map = { // < `=`-sign
    a : "A",
    b : "B",
    c : "C",
    //     ^ comma's, not semicolons
}
```

Now, you'll need to keep in mind that this replacement is case-sensitive.

Comment: Note: the map and join functions don't update the original string so you will need to assign it somewhere.

Comment: @Eyal: I completely forgot about that xD

Comment: Thank you for the comments @Cerbrus. I still need a bit me help getting this going. This is my code so far, what else do I need?
`<textarea name="TextBox" cols="50" rows="5">
</textarea>
<br>
<input type="submit" />
<br>
<textarea name="TextBox1" cols="50" rows="5">
</textarea>

<script>
    
    var map = 
    
    { 
        a : "A",
        b : "B",
        c : "C",
        d : "D",
        e : "E",
        f : "F",
        g : "G",
    }
    
var result = myString.split('')
.map(function(c){
    return map[c];
})
.join('');    
    
</script>`